# Connecting sqlite3 DB with Python - User input

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have a webpage running using FLASK and Python and have a database sqlite3 connected to it. I create a page called guestbook where I am asking the user to enter some details about them: Name, Email, Age, and am sending that information to the server and to the database. I am retrieving it back on the page to show the input from the users.

The entire code here is almost copy/paste from the lectures because the lecturer showed us the code and how it works piece by piece and then it was up to us to glue it together. So when I compare the code they seem same however mine is giving me an error and I just don’t see the mistake. I don’t have any typos, the files have the correct names, the line is exactly the same as my lecturers. I’d be grateful if you could point out my mistake.

When I run the python file it runs ok, or atleast I think so Print Screen of running python file

[image]

How ever the page doesn't load up, and its confusing that in the command window I can't see the error since I activated the debugger, it usually writes the error. So I am lost where is the mistake, cause I don't know where to look.

Internal Server Error

[image]

Python code:

```
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
DB_FILE = 'mydb'

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('PragueMainPage.html')
#----------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/history')
def history():
    return render_template('History.html')
#----------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/gallery')
def gallery():
    return render_template('Gallery.html')
#----------------------------------------------------------

@app.route('/guestbook', methods=['POST'])
def guestbook():
    _insert(request.form['Name'], request.form['Email'], request.form['Age'])
    return redirect(url_for('view'))

def _insert(name, email, age):
    params = {'Name':name, 'Email':email, 'Age':age}
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
    cursor.execute("insert into guestbook VALUES (:name, :email, :age)",params)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()

@app.route ('/guestbook', methods=['POST','GET'])
def view():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM guestbook")
    rv = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template("Guestbook.html",entries=rv)


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/ingridpython.css') }}"/>
        <title> Prague - Guestbook</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div class ="flex-container">
   <div class ="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href ='/'>Main Page </a></li>
            <li><a href ='history'>History </a></li>
            <li><a href ='gallery'>Gallery </a></li>
            <li><a href ='guestbook'>Guestbook </a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>   
</div>

<div id ="guestContainer">
    <form action ="{{url_for('guestbook')}}" method = post>
        Enter name:   <input type ="text"   name ="Name">
        Enter E-mail: <input type ="email"  name ="Email">
        Enter Age:    <input type ="text"   name ="Age">
        <input class ="submit" type ="submit" value ="Submit">
    </form>
 </div>

<div id ="guestContainerAnswer">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th width ="350"> Guest name</th>
            <th width ="600"> Guest E-mail</th>
            <th width ="100"> Guest Age</th>
        </tr>
        {% for entry in entries %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ entry[0]}}</th>
            <th>{{ entry[0]}}</th>
            <th>{{ entry[0]}}</th>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %} 
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `method = post` in `<form action` to `method='POST'`. The complete line should be:

```
<form action ="{{url_for('guestbook')}}" method = 'POST'>
```

Comment: OMG THAT WAS IT!!!!! THANK YOU! IT WORKS! After hours of looking at the damn code! YES!!!! **FIREWORKS**